# brace after variable in PHP

Tags: php

Snippet below ..

```
function _uniord($c) {
    if (ord($c{0}) >=0 && ord($c{0}) <= 127)
      return ord($c{0});
    if (ord($c{0}) >= 192 && ord($c{0}) <= 223)
      return (ord($c{0})-192)*64 + (ord($c{1})-128);
    if (ord($c{0}) >= 224 && ord($c{0}) <= 239)
      return (ord($c{0})-224)*4096 + (ord($c{1})-128)*64 + (ord($c{2})-128);
    if (ord($c{0}) >= 240 && ord($c{0}) <= 247)
      return (ord($c{0})-240)*262144 + (ord($c{1})-128)*4096 + (ord($c{2})-128)*64 + (ord($c{3})-128);
    if (ord($c{0}) >= 248 && ord($c{0}) <= 251)
      return (ord($c{0})-248)*16777216 + (ord($c{1})-128)*262144 + (ord($c{2})-128)*4096 + (ord($c{3})-128)*64 + (ord($c{4})-128);
    if (ord($c{0}) >= 252 && ord($c{0}) <= 253)
      return (ord($c{0})-252)*1073741824 + (ord($c{1})-128)*16777216 + (ord($c{2})-128)*262144 + (ord($c{3})-128)*4096 + (ord($c{4})-128)*64 + (ord($c{5})-128);
    if (ord($c{0}) >= 254 && ord($c{0}) <= 255)    //  error
      return FALSE;
    return 0;
  }   //  function _un
```

From the code which includes  `ord($c{0})`  I never seen before, can anyone tell me what does this mean?  I google a lot and find nothing.

Comment: Well looking at your history I guess you don't accept answers.

Comment: @chris85  Sorry,I did not know the rules,so how to accept this answers？ （just tell me the steps）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is another way of accessing array elements.

`$c{0}` and `$c[0]` will function the same.

> Both square brackets and curly braces can be used interchangeably for accessing array elements

-http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Demo: https://eval.in/652193

Comment: OK,I have accept it.

Answer (score 2):

just like '[]',

```
<?php
$aa = array(1, 2);
echo $aa{1};
echo $aa[1];
```

will output

```
2
2
```